# Java How do I make this flag?

Tags: java

```
int height = grid.getHt();
int width = grid.getWd();
//Paints everything Blue
for(int c=0;c<height;c++){
    for(int d=0;d<width;d++){
        grid.setColor(c,d,Color.CYAN);
    }    
}
//Paints a Yellow Line
for(int c=(height/3);c<((height*2)/3);c++){
    for(int d=0;d<width;d++){
        grid.setColor(c, d, Color.YELLOW);
    }
}
//makes the triangle
int temp;
temp = 0;
for(int d=0;d<(width-2)/4;d++){
    for(int c=0+temp;c<height-temp;c++){
        grid.setColor(c,d,Color.BLACK);
    }
    temp++;
}
//Makes that last black dot at the end of the triangle
if(height<=9){
    for(int c=(height-1)/2;;){
        for(int d=0;d<=(width-2)/4;d++){
            grid.setColor(c,d,Color.BLACK);
        }
    }
} else { 
    for(int j=0; j<=2; j++){
        int z=0;
        for(int c=0;c<(height-1)/2;c++){
            for(int d=0;d<=(width-2)/4;d++){
                grid.setColor(c-1,d,Color.BLACK);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So i'm supposed to draw this flag using java grids, this is what i currently have. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/U00ml.png
at size 9 it looks fine, but at size 12 it is missing a black dot. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no symmetrical place to put "a black dot".

9 is an odd number, 12 is an even number.

For 9 rows, the axis of symmetry goes through the middle of the middle row.  For 12 rows, the axis of symmetry goes between two middle rows.

Comment: So how would I fix that?

Comment: @daniel  Why do you say it needs fixing?   Mathematics (including geometry) rules the universe.  Flags are generally symmetrical.

Comment: Then where am I going wrong?: The size 12 picture is part of the assignment. 
The flag for Bahamas has three equal horizontal stripes with a BLACK triangle to the far left.
• The top-most third is CYAN
• The middle third is YELLOW
• The right-most third is CYAN
• The height specified by the user for this flag must be a multiple of three.
• If a non-multiple of three value is given, the error flag must be drawn instead.

Comment: @daniel  That doesn't seem wrong.  Both your flags have 3 equal stripes.